# Table type in OBJECT

Tags: oracle, plsql

У меня в пакете есть тип

```
type test_rec is record(
    mm Test.mm%type
    );
```

Теперь нужно создать глобальный объект для использования его в нескольких пакетах:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE test_rec is OBJECT (
 mm Test.mm%type
)
```

Получаю ошибку: Ошибка: PLS-00201: identifier 'Test.mm' must be declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%type`, как и `%rowtype` - это синтаксис PL/SQL. В SQL не поддерживается. Поэтому, если кратко, создать полноценный (а не внутри пакета) тип, ссылающийся на тип определённого столбца таблицы или на весь набор столбцов таблицы нельзя. К сожалению.